# Django 5 and Python 3.12.1 send_mail fails with SSL error

Tags: python, django, ssl, upgrade

I have a working application using Django 3.2.6 and Python 3.9.6.  I'm trying to upgrade to Django 5 and Python 3.12.1.  So far, I've managed to track down and fix a number of problems caused by various changes and deprecations but this one has had me stumped for several days.

Using Django `send_mail()` in the new environment fails with `ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: IP address mismatch, certificate is not valid for '40.99.213.34'. (_ssl.c:1000)`.

Note: I need to use the IPV4 address for the connection because using the actual hostname on my linux server causes a delay of around 2 minutes while the default IPV6 address times out and falls back to IPV4.  Using the hostname string on my Win10 dev environment works fine.

Here's a code extract:

```
settings.py

EMAIL_HOST = socket.gethostbyname('smtp.office365.com')  # resolves IPV4 address
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'name@company.co.uk'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

```
views.py

send_mail('Subject','Message Body','name@company.co.uk',['name@gmail.com'])
```

If I add the following line to my settings (gleaned from SO after hours of searching), the error changes to something even less helpful: `[SSL] PEM Lib (_ssl.c:3917)`

```
import certifi
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE = certifi.where()
```

It seems clear that something has changed in the way ssl connects, maybe it's insisting on verifying certs in a different way than it did in Python 3.9.6.  I've spent many hours fruitlessly searching for a solution.  I've looked at the source for the django smtp module and the python ssl module and in desperation even the cpython _ssl module, but I can't figure out what I need to do to overcome this.  If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

After more trial and error I changed the EMAIL_HOST setting to:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.office365.com'
```

Now the certificate domain matches the connection domain, whereas it was an IP address before which didn't match.

This is a bit unsatisfying but it might help other people.

BTW, the long delay in connecting from my linux server seems to have gone away as well.  Perhaps something was fixed in the later versions of one of the packages involved.